# How to copy whole workbook to a desired location by changing a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel workbook containing 5 sheets and a drop-down button in sheet-3. I want to save the entire file when i choose a option from the drop-down button with the drop-down selected option to a desired folder. It would be great if anyone can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) might help you to improve your question.

Comment: I'm using this code. Sub SaveToDesktop()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs "D:\R" & "\" & Format(Now, "1") & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Name
            '.Close
        End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Completed" 'To let you know when it is done
End Sub

Comment: Edit your question with the additional code / question details.

Comment: By selecting an option from the drop-down button, the whole workbook is getting saved by a specified name. But i want to save the file as the option which i am selecting from the drop-down button. Hope this will clear the question requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the drop down's name, then this should work:

```vb
Sub SaveToDesktop()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim strName As String
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Shapes("Drop Down Name")   'Set your drop down name
        strName = .List(.Value) 'get the selected value
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs "D:\R\" & strName
        '.Close
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Completed" 'To let you know when it is done
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but unfortunately it is not working or may what i am assigning the name of drop down name is not working. Suggest me the overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Change event:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Path As String

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then 'Change the range to fit your needs

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            Path = Target.Value

            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\R\" & Path

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        MsgBox "Completed"

    End If

End Sub
```

**Notes:**

1. It s a good idea to include the extension of the file you want to save.
2. You may need to check if the file exist in order to handle each situation accordingly.
3. Avoid Active, instead use Thisworkbook or it s name.